# single table dump/backup using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I want single table (MySQL) backup/dump using PHP. Actually I am working on remote database server from my PC (XAMMP server is not installed on my PC). I tried following command:

```
$command = "mysqldump -u username -p databaname tablename > filepath";
```

Here password is empty (`-p`), I execute it using `system($command, $result);`
result contains 1 and this command creates an empty file. I searched for this problem and found that there shouldn't be space between `-ppassword`. I tried this but the problem is same. is there another way to do this without command in PHP or what should I fix in this command?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<?php

$filename = 'database_backup_'.date('G_a_m_d_y').' . sql';

$result = exec('mysqldump database_name table1 table2 table3 --password=your_pass --user=root --single-transaction >/var/backups/' . $filename, $output);

if(!empty($output)) {
    var_dump($output);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But table name is not defined in command? I want backup of single table.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump -u yourUsername -p yourdatabasename yourtablename > yourdumptablename.sql
```

then hit enter so you ask for password of your db